# jQuery AJAX in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm working with `Symfony` 1.4 and we have a problem with `IE7`

We have a form and an url, when we click the url we want to display a copy of the first form.
Number maximum of forms to display is 3

Now the problem is when we click the first time the second form display. But in the third time it blocks.

Here is the AJAX script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a#add_contact_anchor').click( function() {
        var select_default_values = new Array();
        var array_counter = 0;

        $(this).parents('div#activity_contact_container').find('input').each( function(){
            select_default_values[array_counter] = { value: $(this).val(), name: $(this).attr('id')};
            array_counter++;
        });
        $(this).parents('div#activity_contact_container').find('select').each( function(){
            select_default_values[array_counter] = { value: $(this).val(), name: $(this).attr('id')};
            array_counter++;
        });

        var params = { default_contact_values: select_default_values, contact_num: <?php echo $contact_num; ?> };

        ajaxCallObj = { page: '<?php echo url_for('myCommunication/updateContactsForCatalog', true); ?>', data: params, update: '#activity_contact_container' };
        ajaxCall(ajaxCallObj);  

    });
</script>
```

And here is the url :

```
<a title="<?php echo __('Add new contact 3019'); ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" id="add_contact_anchor"><?php echo __('Add new contact 3019'); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try and move the counter outside the click function callback, probably you're just continuing overwriting the second form.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Please, accept the answer if it was useful.